# The requested resource is not available in struts2 File upload

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to Struts2 and am developing a web application with file upload option. Everything has been configured but when i run the module HTTP Status 404 error: The requested resource is not available. (Link: `http://localhost:8080/File_Upload/index.jsp`). please find below my config, 
index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
<title>File Upload</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/ajaxfileupload.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">  
    function ajaxFileUpload()  
    {  

        $("#loading")  
        .ajaxStart(function(){  
            $(this).show();  
        })//  
        .ajaxComplete(function(){  
            $(this).hide();  
        });//  

        $.ajaxFileUpload  
        (  
            {  
                url:'fileUploadAction.action',//  
                secureuri:false,//false  
                fileElementId:'myFile',//id  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />  
                dataType: 'json',// json  
                success: function (data, status)  //  
                {  
                    //alert(data.message);//jsonmessage,messagestruts2  
                    $("#file_name").attr("value",data.myFile);
                    $("#file_path").attr("value",data.myFileFileName);
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')  
                    {  
                        if(data.error != '')  
                        {  
                            alert(data.error);  
                        }else  
                        {  
                            alert(data.myFile);  
                        }  
                    }  
                },  
                error: function (data, status, e)//  
                {  
                    alert(e);  
                }  
            }  
        )  

        return false;  

    }  
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
   <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="myFile">Upload your file</label>
      <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile"/>
      <input type="button" value="" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">
      <input type="hidden" name="file_name[]" id="file_name[]" value=""/>
      <input type="hidden" name="file_path[]" id="file_path[]" value=""/> 
      <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
   <div id="loading"><span style="position: fixed;left: 50%;top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); color:#f3cbbb ">
   <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" width="200" height="200" style="padding-left:85px">
   <br /><br />
   <span style=" font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px">Please wait,File is being uploaded
   </span></span>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="fileUploadAction" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.MultipleFileUploadAction">  
              <result type="json" name="success">  
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>  
            </result>  
            <result type="json" name="error">  
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>  
            </result> 
        </action> 
   </package>
</struts>
```

Action.class:

```
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.IOException; 
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class MultipleFileUploadAction extends ActionSupport {

    private File[] myFile;
       private String[] myFileContentType;
       private String[] myFileFileName;
       private String destPath;

       public String execute()
       {
          /* Copy file to a safe location */
          destPath = "E:/kalidass/Upload/";

          try{


             for(int i=0;i<myFile.length;i++)
             {
                System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile[i]);
                 System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName[i]);
             File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName[i]);
             FileUtils.copyFile(myFile[i], destFile);
             }

          }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             return "error";
          }

          return "success";
       }
       public File[] getMyFile() {
          return myFile;
       }
       public void setMyFile(File[] myFile) {
          this.myFile = myFile;
       }
       public String[] getMyFileContentType() {
          return myFileContentType;
       }
       public void setMyFileContentType(String[] myFileContentType) {
          this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
       }
       public String[] getMyFileFileName() {
          return myFileFileName;
       }
       public void setMyFileFileName(String[] myFileFileName) {
          this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
       }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app>  
  <filter>  
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
   <filter-class>  
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter  
   </filter-class>  
  </filter>  
  <filter-mapping>  
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
  </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

jar files:
[Jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AA1N.png)

Comment: What part of this code doesn't work?

Comment: View part of index page. index.jsp file. please check my config whether it is correct or not.

Comment: You don't have an action for your index page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in your **struts.xml** this action inside your **default** package

```
<action name="index">
    <result>/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In this way when you'll try to open http://localhost/myapp/index it will return the `index.jsp`